# Array of hash tables not output

Tags: powershell

This is a basic question but I'm stuck. I have the below code:

```
$array = @(
    $hashtable1 = @{
        Name = "Test1"
        Path = "C:\Test1"
    }
    $hashtable2 = @{
        Name = "Test1"
        Path = "C:\Test1"
    }
)
```

The array is created but empty. I have tried comma separation:

```
$hashtable1 = @{}, $hashtable2 = @{}
```

But this did not work. What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assigning the hashtables as variables. Take out the variable assignment:

```
$array = @(
    @{
        Name = "Test1"
        Path = "C:\Test1"
    },
    @{
        Name = "Test1"
        Path = "C:\Test1"
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

[gms0ulman's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53705928/45375) provides an effective solution for constructing your array of hashtables.

To provide some **background information**:

- A variable assignment such as `$hashtable1 = ...` is *not an expression*, so it produces *no output*, which is why your `$array =` assignment ended up containing an *empty array*, given that `@(...)` saw no output.
- However, you can make assignment statements produce output simply by enclosing them in `(...)`, which turns them into *expressions*, which allows you to assign to the variable *and* output the assigned value.
- `@(...)` is *not* needed to construct arrays; instead, you can use `,`, the array-construction operator.

Even though it may not be needed, the following demonstrates how to both construct the array of hashtables *and* save the individual hashtables in dedicated variables:

```
$array =
  ($hashtable1 = @{
      Name = "Test1"
      Path = "C:\Test1"
  }),
  ($hashtable2 = @{
      Name = "Test1"
      Path = "C:\Test1"
  })
```